# Populate array members after the declaration

Tags: java, constructor, initialization

My class has an array as one of it's members. Inside the constructor, I want to populate it's members to the following. How can I do that, it gives me an error.

```
public class GetCurrentMonth {

    Calendar now;
    String[] monthNames;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public GetCurrentMonth() {
        now = Calendar.getInstance();
        monthNames = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
    }

    public String getMonth()
    {
        return monthNames[(now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)];
    }
}
```

I do not want to add these month names at the constructor as follows, since I want to follow good coding practice, and I was told that all initializations should be done inside the constructor.

```
String[] monthNames = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
```

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, not only is it *not* good practice to initialize in the constructor, it's actually *bad* practice, because:

- you actually have to code a constructor (adding useless code)
- fields should be `static final` if they're the same for every instance, like the months
- instance fields should `final` where possible and be initialised on declaration if there's only one way to initialize them

Best practice, including adhering to naming standards, says your class should look like this:

```
public class GetCurrentMonth {
    private static final String[] MONTH_NAMES = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
    private final Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

    public String getMonth() {
        return MONTH_NAMES [(now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to create the array with new String[]

```
monthNames = new String[] {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I agree with the answer from Bohemian♦, But I even would go further and recommend that you create an Enum that holds your month names. Here is how I would do it:

```
public enum Month {
    JANUARY("January"), 
    FEBRUARY("February"), 
    MARCH("March"), 
    APRIL("April"), 
    MAY("May"),
    JUNE("June"), 
    JYLY("July"), 
    AUGUST("August"), 
    SEPTEMBER("September"),
    OCTOBER("October"), 
    NOVEMBER("November"), 
    DECEMBER("December");

    private String displayName;

    private Month(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return displayName;
    }

    public static Month valueOfIgnoreCase(String value) {
        return valueOf(value.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```